# Get Item Text in ListActivity GreenDroid

Tags: android

Hy!

My Code:

```
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {

        final TextItem i = (TextItem) getListView().getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

This didn't return the itemtext, instead it returns :greendroid.widget.item.TextItem@44c1f290

please helo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the reference to the TextItem itself, not the underlying text. You need a way to get the underlying text. Does your ItemText class have a `getText()` method, or something similar?